# Receiving an undefined result from an HTTP POST Request in an Angular DataFactory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular.js and trying to use factory for sending data via http post request. I am getting this error `Cannot read property 'success' of undefined` here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.factory('DataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                setData: function(stud) {
                    return
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test_post.asp',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        },
                        data: stud
                    });

                }
            }

        }]);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, DataFactory) {

            var stud = {
                name: "Alex",
                city: "Berlin"
            };


            DataFactory.setData(stud).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.error(err)
                })
                .finally(function() {
                    console.log("Finished the chain");
                });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The error I am getting is at line DataFactory.setData(stud).success... any help much appreciated...

Comment: just use `.then(successFn, failFn)`, or `.then(fn).catch(fn)`

Comment: Where to use .then... Can you show some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just markdown or do you have  a newline between return and $http? If you return there, $http becomes unreachable. Functions can be below the return, since they are registered before code execution.

So you should write it like

`return $http({...})`

instead of

`return
$http({...})`

Comment: Yes, totally agree

Answer (score 3):

So the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) state:

```
var promise = someAsyncMethodCall();
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
});
```

See the bottom, there are 2 functions to pass to the `then` function. So your code is:

```
DataFactory.setData(stud).then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
}, function (err) {
     console.error(err)
});
```

The $q library is what $http uses under the hood.

See the [promise api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).

There are these methods:

> **then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)** – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.
>
> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using promise chaining). It also notifies via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise cannot be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.
>
> **catch(errorCallback)** – shorthand for promise.then(null, errorCallback)
>
> **finally(callback, notifyCallback)** – allows you to observe either the fulfillment or rejection of a promise, but to do so without modifying the final value. This is useful to release resources or do some clean-up that needs to be done whether the promise was rejected or resolved. See the full specification for more information.

So to further your code, you could do:

```
DataFactory.setData(stud).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err)
})
.finally(function () {
    console.log("Finished the chain");
});
```

## --- EDIT ---

For completeness, there was another error that @Duncan said, that is the line break:

```
app.factory('DataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        setData: function(stud) {
            return
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test_post.asp',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: stud
            });

        }
    }

}]);
```

The break between `return` and `$http({` is causing an error. So it needs to look like this:

```
app.factory('DataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        setData: function(stud) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test_post.asp',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: stud
            });

        }
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really helpful to understand JS promises... I just changed the code and again getting Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: @CallumLinington, all good advice but the problem is that his code isn't actually calling `$http`.

Comment: Working now. Bunch of Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$http` returns a `Promise`. you need to use `.then()` to register a callback on success.

The more general form is `.then(successFn, failFn)`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the function `setData()`:

```
                return
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test_post.asp',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    data: stud
                });
```

That is two statements: `return` just returns from the function, then the call to `$http()` is additional code that is never reached.

Be careful where you put line breaks in Javascript, move the `$http({` up to the previous line.

Oh, and as others have said, using `.success` on the result from `$http` calls is deprecated, switch to using the normal promise methods instead.

Comment: Beat me to it. This is the real problem here.

Comment: @DerekMT12 there are two "real" problems, deprecated function and line breaks

Comment: @CallumLinington but the deprecated function is purely a style issue: the code will still run with the call to the deprecated function.

Comment: @Duncan, lets hope they never remove that function completely.